# Issue running sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pm2

I'm trying to run my sails application with pm2. But if I run "node app.js" I got this:

```
/my_app/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/userconfig/index.js:41
        sails.modules.loadUserConfig(function loadedAppConfigModules (err, userConfig) {
                      ^                                            
TypeError: sails.modules.loadUserConfig is not a function
at Hook.loadModules (/home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/userconfig/index.js:41:27)
at Hook.wrapper [as loadModules] (/home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3250:19)
at Array.modules (/home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/index.js:79:27)
at /home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:591:38
at _arrayEach (/home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:85:13)
at Object.async.auto (/home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:552:9)
at Hook.load (/home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/index.js:73:13)
at Hook.wrapper [as load] (/home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3250:19)
at loadHook (/home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:90:17)
at userconfig (/home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:131:11)
at /home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:713:13
at iterate (/home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
at /home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:274:29
at /home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
at /home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:17
at /home/ubuntu/web-crawler/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

sails version: sails@0.12.13
node version: v8.4.0

I will appreciate any idea...

Comment: Does the app run with `sails lift`?

Comment: yes, it does, with "sails lift" everything is fine

Comment: That's pretty weird.  I'd start by re-installing the node modules in your project.  `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I got the same error. I have another project in the same aws instance and is working with "node app.js". That's pretty weird indeed

Comment: did you get answer ?

Comment: No , If you have any idea I will appreciate

Answer (score -1):

Some how, there was a differences in my app.js, I compared with a new project and the app.js file was different, I replaced the content with the new one and now is working